# WildFly, never start in 0.0.0.0

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to open the connection to WildFly for all the local network. When I set the hostname to `localhost` it works normally but just on this computer.

[image]

But when I change the hostname to `0.0.0.0`, it never finishes the starting process and it makes the IDE useless and makes other IDE tasks wait with following message:

> Waiting another process to finish

[image]

Comment: @Joni open the access to my 192.168.0.22:8080, for all the computers in the network... that what people say to do... you know the solution

Comment: @Joni - I assume he is referring to jboss binding address. When you set the binding address to 0.0.0.0, it tells jboss to listen on all interfaces.

Comment: OK. Yes, changing the bind address to 0.0.0.0 should work.

Comment: @Joni that why i made this question u.u

Comment: I'm sorry @user3284660. From a quick read it seemed you were trying to *connect* using 0.0.0.0 as the address. It seems I wasn't the only one confused because someone upvoted the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same issue in the past.

If you are using JBoss tools plugin, try changing the 'Startup Poller'. It usually takes 'JBoss 7 Manager Service', Web Port or Timeout. I have mine set to 'JBoss 7 Manager Service'.

You can find this, by double clicking on your server and under the section 'Server State Detectors'. These state detectors tell the plugin how to figure out whether your server has started or stopped completely.

Comment: worked but, but not using "JBoss 7 Manager Service" or in my case "Wildfly manager Service"... i setted it to WEB PORT, for shutdown too, using Wildfly never finish, but using web port work correctly, thanks!